# Tkinter adding tag to text (python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want all the `print`'s in my text editor to be purple. When I'm coding it, it looks for each occurrence of `print` in my code, and tries to add a tag to it. Unfortunately, it's giving me an error that unicode strings don't work with it?

```
def convertToPyTags(self, blah=None):
    # Run every time a key is pressed, I know that works
    indexes = [] # This works
    textdata = self.texteditor.get("1.0",END) # This works
    print textdata
    print list(textdata), "L" + str(len(textdata)) # This works
    for i in len(textdata): 
        if (textdata[i:(i+7)] == " print "): # This is where it gives an error
            indexes.insert(len(indexes), i)
    print indexes

""" OUTPUT """

[u'p', u'r', u'i', u'n', u't', u' ', u'"', u'H', u'e', u'l', u'l', u'o', u' ', u'w', u'o', u'r', u'l', u'd', u'!', u'"', u'\n'] L21
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "script", line 145, in keyPress
self.convertToPyTags()
File "script", line 136, in convertToPyTags
for i in len(textdata):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I don't know what this means - apparently integers aren't iterable?

Again, [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=pGra5CNh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
for i in len(textdata):
```

... the `for` loop is expecting a list of items (an "iterable"). However, you're giving it a number, which is why the error says "int is not iterable". If you want to iterate over the textdata, do `for i in textdata`.

Your other choice is to use `range()`, which will return a list of numbers in a range. So, if you want to do a loop using numbers, you can do `for i in range(len(textdata))`.